# Google analytics deprecated login

Tags: java, google-analytics, deprecated

I have the follwing code to access **Google analytics**, to authenticate a user:

```
import com.google.gdata.client.analytics.AnalyticsService;

// Client Login Authorization.
analyticsService.setUserCredentials(clientUsername, clientPassword);
```

But this method is deprecated and can't access anymore. How could I access?
I have heard that is necessary to use

> oAuth2.0

Comment: Could you post the message you obtain?

Answer (score 1):

[Hello Analytics API: Java quickstart for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java)

This tutorial can help you do what you need.

[code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/samples/service-java.txt)

Happy coding